# Cam streaming Flash client/widget

Tags: actionscript, video-streaming, flash, rtmp

I'm looking for a Flash widget that does this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k22AC.png

That's from a webcam streaming site that does what I need, the four boxes are a screenshot of each step of their widget:

Connecting screen, enable webcam prompt, configure and broadcast with a cam preview, broadcasting window with a cam preview with option to stop broadcast.

It doesn't need to be exactly the same, just something similar. Are there any open-source solutions or packages that offer this that I can use on my website? I'm open to the idea of coding it myself, but I've never touched Flash before, so I'll need help with resources on what I'll need to create such a widget. Preferably there's something out there that does this already, or close to this, that I can modify to meet my needs.

The only thing I found was this: https://github.com/AF83/webcam-streaming -- but it doesn't provide any interface or configuration window, it just starts streaming straight away. I could potentially modify this if there's no other options out there, but I have no idea how to add all of those UI elements, how to hook them together, or what software I need to do so. If this is the only option I have, can you please point me in the right direction in learning how to do that (I use Windows 7 64bit).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly what you need : [an open source publisher in flash with video preview](http://raspi.monaserver.ovh/MonaClients/VideoPublisher/). The source code is on github at https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients/.

This is our sample and it work with [MonaServer](http://monaserver.ovh) installed on our raspberry pi, this is good for testing but for production you will need to install an RTMP or RTMFP server. If you want to use MonaServer you can go to our [installation page](http://www.monaserver.ovh/installation.html) or download the windows binary from sourceforge : http://sourceforge.net/projects/monaserver/files/MonaServer_Windows_32.zip/download

Then if you want to modify the source code and implement a better-looking client you can use [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), it's free and complete.

For information it is also possible to broadcast with [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) and HTML5 rather than RTMP/RTMFP and Flash.